# Can the word "forbear" be used as a noun?

Tags: word-usage

This is a sentence from a reading comprehension workbook.

> These are the parents of the new generation, which, by simple inheritance, possesses all the qualities of "toughness" inherent in its forbears.

This was the first time I saw the word "forbear" being used as a noun, so I looked it up in Merriam-Webster but the entry doesn't include any information about the word's usage as a noun. Is the sentence grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I voted to close, because the noun *forbear* is on the [M-W website](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forbear)  with its definition and the note "Less common spelling of forebear". See also [Onelook](https://www.onelook.com/?w=Forbear&ls=a) with multiple returns.

Comment: Did I attract a -1 because the question was closed, @Clare?  I am new here and trying to figure things out. I expect it's on the Help page somewhere but I've not yet found it.

Comment: @Livrecache Some people do downvote answers on questions which should be closed, especially if they're not great quality.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks for letting me know that downvotes can be done on that basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.

I too looked at *Merriam-Webster* and I found:

"**forebear**
noun  fore·bear  \ ˈfȯr-ˌber \
variants: or *less commonly forbear*"

As a user of Australian and British English, I would spell the word with an "e" but I am somewhat surprised that M-W does.

Answer (score -1):

I've searched for this on dictionary and I found it can use in Noun.

Forbear (N.) It means patience refrain or who you are descended.